# Not able to locate xpath of an image using webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am trying to access a tab in a png image using selenium Webdriver:

```
div id="navbar6ClickDiv" 
a onclick="return hdlClick('navbar6ClickDiv', 'navbar')" target="workspace" href="/setup.htm"
img width="90" height="23" border="0" src="/xyz.png"
```

I have tried the following ways to access the tab, but nothing worked :

- 1st:

  ```
  WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.id("navbar6ClickDiv"));   
               div.click();
  ```
- 2nd:

  ```
  WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.tagName("img").name("/images/banner/setupt.png"));
                               div.click();
  ```
- 3rd:

  ```
  WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'/images/banner/setupt.png')]"));
               div.click();
  ```

Comment: In what way did it not work? Any Exception? What does it mean "a tab in a png image"? Could you show us a screenshot, please?

Comment: InvalidSelectorException is seen which extends  to NoSuchElementException. Basically it is not able to find the PNG image and click on it. We are trying to find an Xpath of an image which appears like a tab in the page- but actually when we inspect it using a Firebug- it is a PNG image like mentioned above. We need the XPath of that image and then fire a click event.

Comment: Your selections seem to be right (Except that double By statement - I have never seen that - are you sure it works? Gonna try tommorow.) There has to be something else wrong. Could you please provide a simple testcase so anyone could reproduce your behaviour?

Comment: Test Case:1)login to the application 2) Click on a Tab- this tab is found as soon as I login. 3) This tab which i want to click on is a PNG image.  Expected: Webdriver should identify that element and click on it. In the code :navbar6ClickDiv  is unique to that image.                                                                    <div id="navbar6ClickDiv" style="visibility: visible;">
<a onclick="return hdlClick('navbar6ClickDiv', 'navbar')" target="workspace" href="/setup.htm">
<img width="90" height="23" border="0" src="/images/banner/setupt.png">
</a>

Comment: What Martin Spamer said. That is the most common solution. Other than that - look closely at your page. If it contains any `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements, those have to be dealt with, too. [`driver.switchTo().frame()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28java.lang.String%29) should help.

Answer (score 2):

When using WebDriver to test DHTML/AJAX pages it is quite common to find that WebDriver is too quick for the internet latency and browser javascript to render the page.

It is possible the element doesn't exist **yet**.  In Java the WebDriver [WaitUntil](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html) idiom is used to avoid this, by waiting for the container (e.g. div) to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Derive the Complete CSS Selector of the Image.

```
css=a[onclick*='navbar6ClickDiv'] > img[src*='xyz.png']
```

Step 2:

Click on the Image

```
driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("a[onclick*='navbar6ClickDiv'] > img[src*='xyz.png']")
).click();
```